# Not able to insert into database using wpdb->insert query in WordPress

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I have used MySQL.

Here I have created table like this.

```
 function pw_sample_plugin_create_table() {

$created = dbDelta(
  "CREATE TABLE peoplesss (
    ID bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    first_name varchar(60) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    last_name varchar(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    email varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    PRIMARY KEY (ID),
    KEY email (email)
  ) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;"
);

 }
 register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'pw_sample_plugin_create_table' );
```

then I tried to insert data using $wpdb->insert but failed.

```
 global $wpdb;
 $table = $wpdb->prefix.'peoplesss';
 $a= $wpdb->insert( $table, array('first_name' => 'Kishan', 'last_name' => 'Kishan', 'email' => 'kishan.davda'));
```

What should I change to insert data?

Comment: Does your table name has prefix because of use `$wpdb->prefix` in code?

Comment: It doesn't. The `pw_sample_plugin_create_table()` function creates a table called `peoplesss` and not `wp_peoplesss` so OP should drop the `$wpdb->prefix` bit from the code.

Comment: @Kamran so you mean to say don't use prefix right?

Comment: @cabrerahector so you mean don't use prefix right?

Comment: Correct. You don't need it because your table doesn't use it.

Comment: @cabrerahector thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As comments have said, you created a table without the prefix.  The prefix is often `wp_`, meaning your prefixed table name would be `wp_peoplesss`.

Here's the thing. A WordPress plugin that creates unprefixed tables is a rude plugin. Lots of WordPress stuff assumes the prefixes follow conventions.  If yours doesn't, you'll make life harder for your users.

So, please fix your code to apply the prefix when you create the table.

Try something like this:

```
$tbldef = "CREATE TABLE " . $wpdb->prefix . "peoplesss (
    ID bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    first_name varchar(60) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    last_name varchar(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    email varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    PRIMARY KEY (ID),
    KEY email (email)
  ) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;";
$created = dbDelta(tbldef);
```